# Mail PDF attachments shown as 0 KB

Tags: mail.app, macos, pdf, preview, attachments

Since I updated to *macOS Sierra* (10.12.2) PDF attachment are shown with sizes of *0 KB* and a preview is not embedded. Resetting Mail and even re-installing the whole macOS system (factory default, no recovery) did not help.

The only way to read the attachments is to view the e-mail raw data (<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>) and then store it into an **.eml* file. The created *eml* file can then be opened with Apple Mail via <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> and the attachment is readable.

What am I missing? My inbox is *IMAP* not POP3 and my provider is [posteo.de](http://posteo.de).

[image: 0 KB PDF attachment]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Preferences -> Accounts -> specific account, and change the pop-up entry for Attachments from "all" to "last" (or however the "zuletzt" entry is called in english).

Comment: Herzlich willkommen! Bitte nur Englisch benützen; dieses Antwort wird sonst gelöscht.